# Javafx how to load a new fxml file into a scrollpane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I an trying to load a new fxml file into a `scrollpane`. during runtime and on menu Item click function a new fxml file should be loaded in `scrollpane`

for more detail view this image

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiPnk.)

Please help me..

Comment: Please comment it is possible or not and also why it is not possible??

Comment: Sure it's possible. Can you please show the code you have tried, and explain what happens and how it is different from what you want?